# Installed ubuntu-touch package to test Unity8, computer won't start because it can't find data partition

Tags: partitioning, ubuntu-touch, data-recovery, 15.10, unity8

I wanted to try Unity8 on Ubuntu 15.10 and after some searching I found you have to install the `ubuntu-touch` package, I did and after a log out and switching to Unity Touch on the greeter the computer rebooted and it won't start because it can't find the data partition.

It listed the following:

```
Couldn't find data partition. Spawning adbd ...
/scripts/panic/adbd: line 22: can't create /sys/class/android_usb/android0/idVendor: nonexistent directory
/scripts/panic/adbd: line 23: can't create /sys/class/android_usb/android0/idProduct: nonexistent directory
/scripts/panic/adbd: line 24: can't create /sys/class/android_usb/android0/functions: nonexistent directory
/scripts/panic/adbd: line 25: can't create /sys/class/android_usb/android0/enable: nonexistent directory
Segmentation fault

BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
```

and it gave me a `(initramfs)` prompt

Now I am not a super technical user but I can figure most things out, on this one I am stumped.

I am thinking about trying to boot from a live USB and see if I can recover the data (the system in on a SSD and all my user data on a HDD) and worst case scenario just reset everything and install ubuntu from scratch, however if there is something I can try first and be able to recover my system it would be preferable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining because it has nowhere to create Android files (the directory needs to be made). Try rebooting, if that doesn't work, report back to me.

Comment: Did reboot, tried recovery mode and I get the same.

Comment: Some additional details, the computer when turned on goes immediately to the GNU GRUB menu, for some reason I cannot start anything from the USB, need to try with another drive to check if that's the problem. Is there some way to use grub to fix the problem?