# Boot: "Couldn't find data partition. Spawning adbd"

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, adb

Xubuntu 14.04 on a Samsung laptop. Problem similar to the question posed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688663/installed-ubuntu-touch-package-to-test-unity8-computer-wont-start-because-it-c) with the difference that I've not installed `ubuntu-touch`. I had `adb` installed which I then uninstalled and ran `update-grub` but still not booting. Linux kernels up to 3.13.0.61 boot and work fine but newer versions give me this error OR just give me a blank screen.

> initrd: Couldn't find data partition. Spawning adbd ...

[image: kernel panic error picture]

So to summarize, I can't get any kernel newer than 3.13.0.61 to work.

Here is the output of `apt-cache policy *adb android*`:

```
    android-tools-adbd:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.2.2+git20130218-3ubuntu23
  Version table:
     4.2.2+git20130218-3ubuntu23 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
android-emulator:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 20140328-2310-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
     20140328-2310-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
qtubuntu-android:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.54+14.04.20140402-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
     0.54+14.04.20140402-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
libandroid-properties-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.1.0+git20131207+e452e83-0ubuntu12
  Version table:
     0.1.0+git20131207+e452e83-0ubuntu12 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libandroidsdk-common-java:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 22.2+git20130830~92d25d6-1
  Version table:
     22.2+git20130830~92d25d6-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
libandroid-properties1:
  Installed: 0.1.0+git20131207+e452e83-0ubuntu12
  Candidate: 0.1.0+git20131207+e452e83-0ubuntu12
  Version table:
 *** 0.1.0+git20131207+e452e83-0ubuntu12 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
android-src-vendor:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     7-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
libmirclientplatform-android:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.1.8+14.04.20140411-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     0.1.8+14.04.20140411-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
libandroidsdk-sdklib-java:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 22.2+git20130830~92d25d6-1
  Version table:
     22.2+git20130830~92d25d6-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
libandroidsdk-ddmuilib-java:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 22.2+git20130830~92d25d6-1
  Version table:
     22.2+git20130830~92d25d6-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
android-headers:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.2.2-2-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     4.2.2-2-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
androidsdk-traceview:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 22.2+git20130830~92d25d6-1
  Version table:
     22.2+git20130830~92d25d6-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
libandroidsdk-sdkstats-java:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 22.2+git20130830~92d25d6-1
  Version table:
     22.2+git20130830~92d25d6-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
android-copyright:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 20140328-2310-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
     20140328-2310-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
lxc-android-config:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.162
  Version table:
     0.162 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
android:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 20140328-2310-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
     20140328-2310-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
libandroid-json-org-java:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 20121204-20090211-1
  Version table:
     20121204-20090211-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
libandroid-json-org-java-doc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 20121204-20090211-1
  Version table:
     20121204-20090211-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
android-tools-adb:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.2.2+git20130218-3ubuntu23
  Version table:
     4.2.2+git20130218-3ubuntu23 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
android-platform-headers:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libandroidsdk-hierarchyviewerlib-java:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 22.2+git20130830~92d25d6-1
  Version table:
     22.2+git20130830~92d25d6-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
libandroidsdk-swtmenubar-java:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 22.2+git20130830~92d25d6-1
  Version table:
     22.2+git20130830~92d25d6-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
gcc-arm-linux-androideabi:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.20130705.1-0ubuntu7
  Version table:
     0.20130705.1-0ubuntu7 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
libandroidsdk-ddmlib-java:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 22.2+git20130830~92d25d6-1
  Version table:
     22.2+git20130830~92d25d6-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
androidsdk-ddms:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 22.2+git20130830~92d25d6-1
  Version table:
     22.2+git20130830~92d25d6-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
gcc-i686-linux-android:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3
  Version table:
     3 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
libmirplatformgraphics-android:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.1.8+14.04.20140411-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     0.1.8+14.04.20140411-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
android-tools-fastboot:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.2.2+git20130218-3ubuntu23
  Version table:
     4.2.2+git20130218-3ubuntu23 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
android-tools-fsutils:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.2.2+git20130218-3ubuntu23
  Version table:
     4.2.2+git20130218-3ubuntu23 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
androidsdk-hierarchyviewer:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 22.2+git20130830~92d25d6-1
  Version table:
     22.2+git20130830~92d25d6-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
androidsdk-uiautomatorviewer:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 22.2+git20130830~92d25d6-1
  Version table:
     22.2+git20130830~92d25d6-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

Here is the output of update-initramfs

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k 3.13.0-101-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-101-generic
/etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd: 9: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd: /usr/sbin/flash-touch-initrd: not found
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd exited with return code 127
```

dkms does not return anything. Here is the output of dpkg -l linux*  http://paste.ubuntu.com/23609521/

Comment: I wonder why nobody is interested in tackling this problem.

Comment: you're on Ubuntu touch?

Comment: @Reza,  Could you post the output of `apt-cache policy *adb android*` and `dkms status`. Have you run `sudo apt-get autoremove` after uninstalling `adb`? because you have to remove its dependency too. Or was adb installed from external archive, not from Ubuntu repository? That error is from initrd, so update-grub has no effect, so use `update-initramfs -u -k <kernel-version>` replace `<kernel-version>` with with the version of non working kernel. BTW, please do these steps in order, collect info, post them, then try those autoremove & initrd update after that. So your question get details.

Comment: I added the output. No didn't run autoremove because that would remove the working kernel.

Comment: @Reza let me know your results for `dkms status` & `sudo update-initramfs -u -k <kernel-version>`, also post  `dpkg -l linux*` to http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: I added the output.

Comment: @Reza use @ to notify me, any way run `sudo apt-get purge initramfs-tools-ubuntu-touch` , Otherwise remove that residue configuration manually `sudo rm /etc/initramfs/post-update.d/zz-flash-touch-initrd` .  Then again test `sudo update-initramfs -u -k ...` .

Comment: @user.dz I did so. Now I don't get the adb error but am greeted by a blank screen. If I choose safe mode then choose 'resume', it works and I can log in (as I've done right now) but the screen brightness hotckeys on keyboard do not function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49908/discussion-between-user-dz-and-reza).

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround

1. Run purge to remove configuration

   ```
    sudo apt-get purge initramfs-tools-ubuntu-touch
   ```

   Otherwise remove that residue configuration manually

   ```
    sudo rm /etc/initramfs/post-update.d/zz-flash-touch-initrd
   ```
2. Rebuild the RAM Disk for the non working kernels, example

   ```
    sudo update-initramfs -u -k 3.13.0-105-generic
   ```

### Correct answer: Report this bug

You should report this a bug against `initramfs-tools-ubuntu-touch`, it should not leave such configuration that break system if the package was not removed completely.